# How to implement Barcode in canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I would like some help with implementing a Barcode inside my canvas.

I am using ean13.js to produce a Barcode and it works like a charm if adding it to a div (*#controlDiv*).

**However I have a canvas inside which I would like to add this "div".**

My HTML

```
<div>
   <div>
      <input type="button" id="btnGenerateStuffInCanvas" value="Add Stuff"/>
      <input type="button" id="btnGenerateEAN13" value="Generate EAN"/>
   </div>
   <div id="controlDiv">
   </div>
   <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd just set the target to be a canvas instead of a div, before then using the `.drawImage` function of the main canvas's ctx. (The code's github page indicates a canvas can be used as the target)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went at it this way:

I created another canvas which I style to display:none. Then I generated the eancode to this canvas and in another canvas I generated an Image from this canvas which I added to the canvas.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            var myEanCanvas = document.getElementById('myEan');
            new EAN13(myEanCanvas, textToAdd);



            //Create Image from EAN
            var imageObj = new Image();

            imageObj.onload = function () {
                context.drawImage(imageObj, $(parent).attr('positionx'), $(parent).attr('positiony'), $(parent).attr('width'), $(parent).attr('height'));
            };
            imageObj.src = myEanCanvas.toDataURL();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. It works for me. It can be done using Data URI template to create SVG images.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx    = canvas.getContext('2d');

var data   = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">' +
               '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +
                 '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:40px">' +
                   '<div id="controlDiv">s</div>' +
                 '</div>' +
               '</foreignObject>' +
             '</svg>';

var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

img.onload = function () {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}

img.src = url;
```

Replace your html element in data where the div **`<div id="controlDiv">s</div>`** element exists.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xqnqng37/)

I think that it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have DOM elements inside a canvas.
What you can do to cheat it is to have the div overlay the canvas with css.
For instance (css):

```
#controlDiv {
    ...
    margin-top:-100px;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ok. Is there some way to write the ean to the context of the canvas then? Just like writing text or drawing?

Comment: You can try to create an object in the canvas like
`var controlDiv = new Kinetic.Shape({name:'controlDiv'});`
And then try
`new EAN13(stage.get('.controlDiv'), "XXXXXXXXXXXXX");`

Comment: Kinetic is not defined?
n00b :)

Comment: Forgot to mention: if you want to try that approach (it might ot might not work), you need to enhance your canvas with an object-oriented canvas library like KineticJS http://kineticjs.com/